# Campaign/Campaign Member/Opportunities report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

Currently we have a standard salesforce report type for showing the Campaigns with Opportunities.

We want to create a custom report type that shows all Campaign - Opportunities where the campaign members are of a particular type.

This "type" field in Campaign Member  is a picklist.

I tried to clone the standard report type (Campaigns-Opportunities) but looks it is not possible so I tried to create a custom report type but I am not able to link Opportunities at all from Campaigns nor I am able to Campaigns from Opportunities.

All I can do is a create a custom report type between Campaigns - Campaign Members.

Can someone throw some ideas ?

Comment: Is the "Campaigns with opps" report type availble to you to create a new report?

Comment: Yes it is available. But "Campaigns with Opps" is a standard report type from which I cannot clone and I could not add "Campaign Members" object to it.

Comment: I don't get it, you have the Member info right in the Campaigns - Opps standard report so it's already joined